# lsregister, msd and Dock using ~100% of CPU in Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Upgraded to Yosemite 7 days ago on my 2013 MBA and CPU has not stopped maxing out on 2 instances of *lsregister* (one for my username and one for root), one instance of *mds* and one instance of *Dock* since installation.

When I try to find apps in Spotlight (Terminal for example), they are not being found.

This is killing my battery life - I used to get around 8 hours and now I struggle to get 2 hours of life.

Answer (score 0):

`lsregister` registers applications and libraries with the Launch Services database and `mds` (metadata server) serves clients of the metadata APIs like Spotlight.

Try to rebuild the Launch Services database:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Or erase the Spotlight index:

```
sudo mdutil -Ea
```

You can also try to run `sudo lsof|grep lsregister` or `sudo lsof|grep mds` to see if `lsregister` or `mds` gets stuck on processing some particular files.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off Spotlight (added all drives to privacy or using command line as suggested already) and ran the following:

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -u -domain local -domain system -domain user -domain network

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user -domain network

This immediately dropped the CPU usage from 100% down to almost 0%. So far it seems to have fixed my problems. Took a LOT of digging around to finally resolve this.